# Problema con validar URL con expresiones regulares en C#

Tags: c#, regex

Tengo un problema tengo esta expresión regular:

```
Regex Valida = new Regex(@"^(http|ftp|https|www)://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-
Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?$", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

El problema es que no me valida las URL que comienzan con `WWW`.

¿Qué me falta para que la expresión me valide URL como **www.google.com** y como **google.com**?

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://superuser.com/a/623174) te puede ayudar :)

Comment: Por favor prueba esto: `^https?:\/\/[\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)+[/#?]?.*$` La puedes probar aquí: [Regex para IPs y URLs](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex-ejemplos.php?type=mix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiente tu pregunta (¿Qué me falta?), la expresión regular que pones debería encontrar lo que pides.

Lo puedes comprobar **[aquí](https://regex101.com/r/uVjkiM/1/)**.

No sé si lo que quieres decir es que necesitas encontrar lo mismo pero haciendo que el protocolo (http/https/...) sea opcional.

En tal caso, lo puedes lograr metiendolo en un grupo y haciéndolo opcional con `?`. Así `^(?:(http|ftp|https|www)://)?`

[Así funcionaría](https://regex101.com/r/uVjkiM/2/) también para `google.com` y `www.google.com` sin nada delante.

De todas formas, validar una url mediante una expresión regular puede ser más complicado de lo que parece, ya que tiene muchos casos en los que seguramente no hayas pensado.

Lo mejor es utilizar una expresión regular que esté aceptada como correcta y ampliamente probada.

En este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) de SO en inglés se discuten algunas soluciones. Incluso para C# hay una solución sin usar expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción usando Regex puede ser esta

```
string regex = @"(((([a-z]|\d|-|.||~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.||~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).?)(:\d*)?)(/((([a-z]|\d|-|.||~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)+(/(([a-z]|\d|-|.||~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)))?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|.||~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|.||~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|/|\?)*)?$";
string url = "https://www.google.com.ar";
bool isValid = (Regex.IsMatch(url, regex));
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23560633/5213794)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar directamente el siguiente método de C# para validar URLs:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(URL_a_Validar, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

Comment: Lo malo de esta solución, es que, en esencia, lo que valida es que no sea una url invalida, no lo contrario, entonces un `string` común devuelve `true`

Comment: En ese caso puedes realizar la negación: if(!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(URL_a_Validar, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))